# In-line script in IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a simple in-line script in an html page:

```
  <script>
          function keyDown(event, inputId) {

              if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                  startSearch(inputId)
              }
          }

          function startSearch(inputId) {
              var searchText = document.getElementById(
                  inputId).value
              var newLocation =
                  `<%= clientAppUrl %>/search?searchString=${searchText}`

              window.location = newLocation
          }
      </script>
```

It is invoked from an `input` tag:

```
<input id='search1' onkeydown="keyDown(event, 'search1')" placeholder='Bla...' />
```

The script works perfectly in Chrome and Safari and on mobile devices but in IE11 it gives an error `keyDown is undefined`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown The keyDown event is certainly NOT deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IE11 does not support templated strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility), so it's likely that

```
var newLocation = `<%= clientAppUrl %>/search?searchString=${searchText}`
```

Is breaking the entire `<script>` block it's contained within, causing `keyDown` to not be present.  You'll need to rewrite it to not use the interpolated string if you wish to support IE11.

Comment: Yes, I just spotted that myself. Sorry I posted too hastily